# Is `edit` a legal bash command?

Tags: ios, bash

I found the following bash statement in a tutorial:

```
edit ~/.bash_profile
```

When I run it in the terminal (iOS) I get:

```
-bash: edit: command not found
```

Is edit a legal bash command?

Comment: I would assume that they are telling you to edit the file using your favorite text editor (nano, vim, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a *nix program (variant of ex), not a bash shell command.

See `man edit`: [http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?edit+1](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?edit%201)

Answer (score 1):

No. For all builtin shell commands, see `man builtin`. See also: `man bash` for more language-specific stuff of bash.

On my systems (OS X 10.6 and Ubuntu 10.4) edit is a program located in /usr/bin

If you wish to edit a file, try using `nano` instead. Not sure what comes on iOS though.

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix command line any executable program located in your [PATH](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acar.html) is a "legal command." To be a legal *bash* command it would have to be a [bash builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).

On Unix systems it is typical for there to be at least two text editors installed: [ed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?00+00) and [vi](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vi+1). On some systems one or both of these may not be present, perhaps due to disk space issues, but those two can be found on most Unix systems. Other text editors may or may not be installed depending on the whims of your vendor and sysadmin. On a Linux system, for example, it is common to find [nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v1.2/nano.1.html) installed, or some other easy to use command line editor.

One traditional [environment variable](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) name is `EDITOR` which is used to store the name of the command to use to edit text files. Thus, it is a common convention in documentation which is written to be environment-neutral to say

```
$EDITOR some_file
```

When you mean to say that `some_file` should be opened with any text editor available to you.

Whoever wrote the tutorial you are reading did not follow this convention and probably is making an assumption about your environment. If an `edit` command is not normally available in your environment the author of the tutorial could be using `edit` generically as a stand in for the more usual `$EDITOR` convention.